# Laravel 4 paginate and orderBy

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

Normaly I call my database like this :

```
$data = array(
    'one' => MyORM::paginate($this->per_page),

);
return View::make('project.index')->with($data);
```

But I also want to use an **OrderBy** so I can use:

```
$data = array(
    'test' => MyORM::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get(),
);
return View::make('project.index')->with($data);
```

But I don't know how I can "merge" the two codes?

I can also use :

```
$data = array(
    'test2' => DB::table('martialp')
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC') 
        ->paginate(4)
);
```

But my class `MyORM` for exemple is useless with this previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = MyORM::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate(15);

return View::make('project.index', compact('data'));
```

Comment: Why the `compact('data')` not `->whith($data)` ?

Comment: the `compact()` function creates an array containing variables and their values. I've always just preferred it based on personal preference. You can read more here:  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php